# Recursive Search Function

Tags: php, json, recursion

I have strings that come in the form of "IT/Internet/Web Development/Ajax". I parse it and make a JSON Object like

```
[{
  "name": "IT",
  "subcategories":[
   {
    "name": "Internet",
    "subcategories" : [
    {
      "name": "Web Development",
       "subcategories" : [
       {
        "name":"Ajax"
        }]}]}]
```

I create the JSON object by doing

```
$input = "IT/Internet/Web Development";
$items = explode("/", $input);

$parent = null;
$firstObject = null;
while (count($items))
{
 $object = new StdClass();
 $item = array_shift($items);
 $object->name = $item;
 if (count($items) == 0) {
    $object->subcategories=NULL; // I made this null in order to know that this is the last item of the string that comes in
 }
 if ($parent)
    $parent->subcategories = array($object);
 else
    $firstObject = $object;

  $parent = $object;
}
array_push($category_collection, $firstObject); //$category_collection is an array
}
```

When another string comes in, for example "IT/Internet/Browsers", I want to be able to parse the categories that were created and place "Browsers" in the correct place as a subcategory of Internet, so then my JSON object would look like

```
 [{
  "name": "IT",
  "subcategories":[
   {
    "name": "Internet",
    "subcategories" : [
    {
      "name": "Web Development",
       "subcategories" : [
       {
          "name":"Ajax"
        }],
        {
         "name":"Browsers" 
         }}]}]
```

I'm having problems  writing a recursive function that will just loop the JSON Object to categorize everything in the right place. What I am doing as of right now is

```
    $arrlength = count($category_collection); //count the size of the array
    $input = "IT/Internet/Browsers";
    $items = explode("/",$input);
    $tempVariable = array_shift($items);
    $flag = false;
    for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
      //Here I check if the first a category with that name already exists
        if ($category_collection[$x]['name'] == $tempVariable) {
            $flag = true;

                    //Now here is where im having problems doing the recursion to check  if the subcategory2 already exists and then if subcategory 3 and so on...

        }

    }
```

If anybody could guide me on the right direction that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full function, it should work, you can convert it to json after, if you need:

```
$categoriesCollection = array();

$input = "IT/Internet/Web Development";
updateCategoriesCollection(explode('/', $input), $categoriesCollection);
$input = "IT/Internet/Browsers";
updateCategoriesCollection(explode('/', $input), $categoriesCollection);

function updateCategoriesCollection(array $categoriesList, array &$categoriesCollection)
{
    $name = array_shift($categoriesList);
    $category = null;
    foreach ($categoriesCollection as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value->name == $name)
        {
            $category = $value;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$category)
    {
        $category = new StdClass;
        $category->name = $name;
        $categoriesCollection[] = $category;
    }

    if (!empty($categoriesList))
    {
        if (empty($category->subcategories)) $category->subcategories = array();
        updateCategoriesCollection($categoriesList, $category->subcategories);
    }
}
var_dump($categoriesCollection);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => IT
            [subcategories] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Internet
                            [subcategories] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => Web Development
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => Browsers
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the anwer. sorry for the late reply but that was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try this please (Not tested, maybe some error to correct, i am here to help):

```
function boolean check_is_good($array, $input)
{
$element = array_shift($input);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($array), $x++) {
        if ($array[$x]['name'] == $element){
           if ((!isset($array[$x]['subcategories']) && (count($input) == 0))
              return (true);
           else if ((!isset($array[$x]['subcategories']) && (count($input) != 0))
              return (false);
           $newArray = $array[$x]['subcategories'];
           return (check_is_good($newArray, $input));
        }
    }
  return (false);
}
```

The function return true is all is in the correct place

You have to pass in parameter1 an array that represent your JSON ($category_collecton in your example)

You have to pass in parameter2 an array with all elements ($items in your example)